# Fixed: Separate First word and the rest in a string (indexof problem)

Tags: c#

So the problem is I want to separate a string into two string. 1 is for first word and the other is for the second until the last word. I am using index and substring to do this but face with a problem, the index is 0. The string value can be seen in the screenshot.

```
private void findBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string startst = startingStation.Text;
  string endst = endingStation.Text;
  int index = startst.IndexOf(" ");

  string startnum = startst.Substring(0, startst.IndexOf(" "));
  string endnum = endst.Substring(0, endst.IndexOf(" "));

  string startname = startst.Substring(startst.IndexOf(" "), startst.Length);
  string endname = endst.Substring(endst.IndexOf(" "), endst.Length);

  Routes findRoutes = new Routes();
  findRoutes.TextBoxValue = "SomeValue";
  findRoutes.Show();
}
```

This is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What are your strings? Where you substring them? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first word :

```
yourstring.Substring(0,yourstring.IndexOf(" "));
```

To get the remaining words

```
yourstring.Substring(yourstring.IndexOf(" ")+1);
```

Note, this will throw exception when there is no space in the string.

Comment: I put a breakpoint on string startnum = startst.Substring(0, startst.IndexOf(" ")); and the value of startst is "CC21 Holland Village" but startnum is null

Comment: @Wolfeatspotatoes - move to next line you will see the value.

Comment: id add a checker for if the space exist so you don't get the exception